# Associated graded algebra of Clifford algebra $\text{Cl}(V,q)$

Tags: linear-algebra, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

I have been reading Lawson & Michelsohn's *Spin Geometry*, there is a sentence in the proof of Proposition $1.2$ that I don't understand. The proposition is the following:

> For any quadratic form $q$, the associated graded algebra of $\text{Cl}(V,q)$ is naturally isomorphic to the exterior algebra $\Lambda^*V$.

In the proof they define a map $\bigotimes^rV\xrightarrow{\pi_r}\mathscr{F}^r\to\mathscr{F}^r/\mathscr{F}^{r-1}$, $v_{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{i_r}\mapsto[v_{i_1}\cdots v_{i_r}]$, where $\pi_r$ is used in the definition of Clifford algebra, the quotient of the tensor algebra of $V$ by the ideal $\mathscr{I}_q$ which is generated by $v\otimes v+q(V)1$ for $v\in V$. The sentence I don't understand is

> The kernel of $\bigotimes^r V\to\mathscr{F}^r/\mathscr{F}^{r-1}$ consists of the $r$-homogeneous pieces of elements $\varphi\in\mathscr{I}_q$ of degree $\leq r$.

(If we write $\varphi=\sum a_i\otimes(v_i\otimes v_i+q(v_i))\otimes b_i$, then the $r$-homogeneous part is of the form $\varphi_r=\sum a_i\otimes v_i\otimes v_i\otimes b_i$.)

**Questions:** Why is the kernel that? Why is it called the homogeneous part, isn't $q(v_i)$ of the same degree as $v_i\otimes v_i$?

Comment: $q(v_i)$ has degree 0, and $v_i\otimes v_i$ has degree 2 in the tensor algebra ${\mathcal T}(V)$.

Comment: @Threeaggies But the definition of quadratic form is "a polynomial with terms all of degree two", is $q(v_i)$ the coefficient of $v_i^2$ in $q(v)$?

Comment: The value $q(v_i)$ is a real number, so has degree 0 in the tensor algebra. $q$ is just a symmetric bilinear form on $V$, and a typical example is on ${\mathbb R}^n$, $q(v)=v\cdot v$, the dot product.

Comment: To be clear and address the heart of the issue: you are confusing two separate concepts both called "degree". What's relevant here is "the degree of an element of the tensor algebra". The other concept, "the degree of a polynomial", is irrelevant here.